# Trouble sorting HTML table: <td> and <a href>

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-table

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Links Test for Stack</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    #AllTable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      /* Collapse borders */
      width: 100%;
      /* Full-width */
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      /* Add a grey border */
      font-size: 18px;
      /* Increase font-size */
    }
  </style>
</head>



<body>


  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Sort" onclick="sortTable()" ;><br>
  </div>


  <div id="All" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>All Links</h3>
    <table id="AllTable">
      <caption></caption>
      <tr>
        <th>LINK</th>
        <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th>CATEGORY</th>
      </tr>

<tr><td><a href="http://lycos.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Goldie</a></td><td>Goldie description</td><td>Goldie category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://networkadvertising.org" target="_blank" alt="none">Ericha</a></td><td>Ericha description</td><td>Ericha category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://google.cn" target="_blank" alt="none">Karel</a></td><td>Karel description</td><td>Karel category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://addthis.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Jack</a></td><td>Jack description</td><td>Jack category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://purevolume.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Meredith</a></td><td>Meredith description</td><td>Meredith category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://chicagotribune.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Emilia</a></td><td>Emilia description</td><td>Emilia category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://cnn.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Jenifer</a></td><td>Jenifer description</td><td>Jenifer category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://indiatimes.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Wolfy</a></td><td>Wolfy description</td><td>Wolfy category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://multiply.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Jaynell</a></td><td>Jaynell description</td><td>Jaynell category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://mail.ru" target="_blank" alt="none">Melissa</a></td><td>Melissa description</td><td>Melissa category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://archive.org" target="_blank" alt="none">Constantine</a></td><td>Constantine description</td><td>Constantine category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://icio.us" target="_blank" alt="none">Dulsea</a></td><td>Dulsea description</td><td>Dulsea category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://statcounter.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Serene</a></td><td>Serene description</td><td>Serene category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://cyberchimps.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Chad</a></td><td>Chad description</td><td>Chad category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://wikia.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Jeana</a></td><td>Jeana description</td><td>Jeana category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://ow.ly" target="_blank" alt="none">Jody</a></td><td>Jody description</td><td>Jody category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://xrea.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Blinnie</a></td><td>Blinnie description</td><td>Blinnie category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://etsy.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Rene</a></td><td>Rene description</td><td>Rene category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://ocn.ne.jp" target="_blank" alt="none">Pegeen</a></td><td>Pegeen description</td><td>Pegeen category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://redcross.org" target="_blank" alt="none">Shep</a></td><td>Shep description</td><td>Shep category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://nature.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Alasdair</a></td><td>Alasdair description</td><td>Alasdair category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://symantec.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Vanni</a></td><td>Vanni description</td><td>Vanni category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://hibu.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Adamo</a></td><td>Adamo description</td><td>Adamo category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://marketwatch.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Rahal</a></td><td>Rahal description</td><td>Rahal category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://foxnews.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Elbertina</a></td><td>Elbertina description</td><td>Elbertina category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://mtv.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Lauree</a></td><td>Lauree description</td><td>Lauree category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://newyorker.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Elnora</a></td><td>Elnora description</td><td>Elnora category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://rediff.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Mahmud</a></td><td>Mahmud description</td><td>Mahmud category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://last.fm" target="_blank" alt="none">Bette</a></td><td>Bette description</td><td>Bette category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://macromedia.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Sayres</a></td><td>Sayres description</td><td>Sayres category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://bandcamp.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Darci</a></td><td>Darci description</td><td>Darci category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://chronoengine.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Stanley</a></td><td>Stanley description</td><td>Stanley category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://sciencedaily.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Anthony</a></td><td>Anthony description</td><td>Anthony category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://java.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Pryce</a></td><td>Pryce description</td><td>Pryce category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://arstechnica.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Ezmeralda</a></td><td>Ezmeralda description</td><td>Ezmeralda category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://google.de" target="_blank" alt="none">Bliss</a></td><td>Bliss description</td><td>Bliss category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://meetup.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Leigh</a></td><td>Leigh description</td><td>Leigh category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://earthlink.net" target="_blank" alt="none">Merrie</a></td><td>Merrie description</td><td>Merrie category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://comcast.net" target="_blank" alt="none">Dewain</a></td><td>Dewain description</td><td>Dewain category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://nifty.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Dorothee</a></td><td>Dorothee description</td><td>Dorothee category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://springer.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Glennis</a></td><td>Glennis description</td><td>Glennis category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://dailymotion.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Tripp</a></td><td>Tripp description</td><td>Tripp category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://cisco.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Clyve</a></td><td>Clyve description</td><td>Clyve category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://nbcnews.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Corny</a></td><td>Corny description</td><td>Corny category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://t.co" target="_blank" alt="none">Robena</a></td><td>Robena description</td><td>Robena category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://netscape.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Nikolaus</a></td><td>Nikolaus description</td><td>Nikolaus category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://walmart.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Cassie</a></td><td>Cassie description</td><td>Cassie category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Merrilee</a></td><td>Merrilee description</td><td>Merrilee category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://vistaprint.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Kalinda</a></td><td>Kalinda description</td><td>Kalinda category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://hubpages.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Carny</a></td><td>Carny description</td><td>Carny category</td>

    </table>
  </div>


  <script>
    function sortTable() {
      var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
      table = document.getElementById("AllTable");
      switching = true;
      /*Make a loop that will continue until
      no switching has been done:*/
      while (switching) {
        //start by saying: no switching is done:
        switching = false;
        rows = table.rows;
        /*Loop through all table rows (except the
        first, which contains table headers):*/
        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
          //start by saying there should be no switching:
          shouldSwitch = false;
          /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
          one from current row and one from the next:*/
          x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
          y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
          //check if the two rows should switch place:
          if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
            //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
            shouldSwitch = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
          /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
          and mark that a switch has been done:*/
          rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
          switching = true;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

I would like to sort an HTML table - and I have the below script. The trouble is the first column is generated like this, which (bc the script is pointed at the td element) it doesn't sort properly.

```
<td><a href="URL" target="_blank">VALUE_TO_SORT_BY</a></td>
```

Where var x and y are defined, I tried changing td to a, but it didn't work (no sorting at all occurred as far as I could tell)

```
<script>
function sortTable() {
    var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    switching = true;
    /*Make a loop that will continue until
    no switching has been done:*/
    while (switching) {
        //start by saying: no switching is done:
        switching = false;
        rows = table.rows;
        /*Loop through all table rows (except the
        first, which contains table headers):*/
        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
            //start by saying there should be no switching:
            shouldSwitch = false;
            /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
            one from current row and one from the next:*/
            //I think the issue is here, but unsure how to solve
            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
            //check if the two rows should switch place:
            if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                shouldSwitch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
            /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
            and mark that a switch has been done:*/
            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
            switching = true;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should post a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. You can use a Stack Snippet (one of the tools inside the question editor) to do that.

Comment: Could you provide a sample table that isn't sorting properly? Using your code and a quick table I made to try it with, it seems to work properly.

Comment: `rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0]` will throw an error for `i === (rows.length - 1)`

Comment: I changed 'TD' to 'a' where you set the values of 'x' and 'y' and the sorting worked as it should. Are you sure this isn't working? Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good, but this line made the difference: `if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase())` here you're comparing all the `HTML` inside the element not just the text that you want to compare at the end. So, we should rely on the `textContent` attribute instead of the `innerHTML` attribute, the line above becomes: `if(x.textContent.toLowerCase() > y.textContent.toLowerCase())`.

```js
function sortTable() {
    var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
    table = document.getElementById("AllTable");
    switching = true;
    /*Make a loop that will continue until
    no switching has been done:*/
    while (switching) {
        //start by saying: no switching is done:
        switching = false;
        rows = table.rows;
        /*Loop through all table rows (except the
        first, which contains table headers):*/
        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
            //start by saying there should be no switching:
            shouldSwitch = false;
            /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
            one from current row and one from the next:*/
            //I think the issue is here, but unsure how to solve
            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
            //check if the two rows should switch place:
            if (x.textContent.toLowerCase() > y.textContent.toLowerCase()) {
                //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                shouldSwitch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
            /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
            and mark that a switch has been done:*/
            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
            switching = true;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Links Test for Stack</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    #AllTable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      /* Collapse borders */
      width: 100%;
      /* Full-width */
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      /* Add a grey border */
      font-size: 18px;
      /* Increase font-size */
    }
  </style>
</head>



<body>


  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Sort" onclick="sortTable()" ;><br>
  </div>


  <div id="All" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>All Links</h3>
    <table id="AllTable">
      <caption></caption>
      <tr>
        <th>LINK</th>
        <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th>CATEGORY</th>
      </tr>

<tr><td><a href="http://lycos.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Goldie</a></td><td>Goldie description</td><td>Goldie category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://networkadvertising.org" target="_blank" alt="none">Ericha</a></td><td>Ericha description</td><td>Ericha category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://google.cn" target="_blank" alt="none">Karel</a></td><td>Karel description</td><td>Karel category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://addthis.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Jack</a></td><td>Jack description</td><td>Jack category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://purevolume.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Meredith</a></td><td>Meredith description</td><td>Meredith category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://chicagotribune.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Emilia</a></td><td>Emilia description</td><td>Emilia category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://cnn.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Jenifer</a></td><td>Jenifer description</td><td>Jenifer category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://indiatimes.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Wolfy</a></td><td>Wolfy description</td><td>Wolfy category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://multiply.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Jaynell</a></td><td>Jaynell description</td><td>Jaynell category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://mail.ru" target="_blank" alt="none">Melissa</a></td><td>Melissa description</td><td>Melissa category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://archive.org" target="_blank" alt="none">Constantine</a></td><td>Constantine description</td><td>Constantine category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://icio.us" target="_blank" alt="none">Dulsea</a></td><td>Dulsea description</td><td>Dulsea category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://statcounter.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Serene</a></td><td>Serene description</td><td>Serene category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://cyberchimps.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Chad</a></td><td>Chad description</td><td>Chad category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://wikia.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Jeana</a></td><td>Jeana description</td><td>Jeana category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://ow.ly" target="_blank" alt="none">Jody</a></td><td>Jody description</td><td>Jody category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://xrea.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Blinnie</a></td><td>Blinnie description</td><td>Blinnie category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://etsy.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Rene</a></td><td>Rene description</td><td>Rene category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://ocn.ne.jp" target="_blank" alt="none">Pegeen</a></td><td>Pegeen description</td><td>Pegeen category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://redcross.org" target="_blank" alt="none">Shep</a></td><td>Shep description</td><td>Shep category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://nature.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Alasdair</a></td><td>Alasdair description</td><td>Alasdair category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://symantec.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Vanni</a></td><td>Vanni description</td><td>Vanni category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://hibu.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Adamo</a></td><td>Adamo description</td><td>Adamo category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://marketwatch.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Rahal</a></td><td>Rahal description</td><td>Rahal category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://foxnews.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Elbertina</a></td><td>Elbertina description</td><td>Elbertina category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://mtv.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Lauree</a></td><td>Lauree description</td><td>Lauree category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://newyorker.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Elnora</a></td><td>Elnora description</td><td>Elnora category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://rediff.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Mahmud</a></td><td>Mahmud description</td><td>Mahmud category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://last.fm" target="_blank" alt="none">Bette</a></td><td>Bette description</td><td>Bette category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://macromedia.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Sayres</a></td><td>Sayres description</td><td>Sayres category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://bandcamp.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Darci</a></td><td>Darci description</td><td>Darci category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://chronoengine.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Stanley</a></td><td>Stanley description</td><td>Stanley category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://sciencedaily.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Anthony</a></td><td>Anthony description</td><td>Anthony category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://java.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Pryce</a></td><td>Pryce description</td><td>Pryce category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://arstechnica.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Ezmeralda</a></td><td>Ezmeralda description</td><td>Ezmeralda category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://google.de" target="_blank" alt="none">Bliss</a></td><td>Bliss description</td><td>Bliss category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://meetup.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Leigh</a></td><td>Leigh description</td><td>Leigh category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://earthlink.net" target="_blank" alt="none">Merrie</a></td><td>Merrie description</td><td>Merrie category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://comcast.net" target="_blank" alt="none">Dewain</a></td><td>Dewain description</td><td>Dewain category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://nifty.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Dorothee</a></td><td>Dorothee description</td><td>Dorothee category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://springer.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Glennis</a></td><td>Glennis description</td><td>Glennis category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://dailymotion.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Tripp</a></td><td>Tripp description</td><td>Tripp category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://cisco.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Clyve</a></td><td>Clyve description</td><td>Clyve category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://nbcnews.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Corny</a></td><td>Corny description</td><td>Corny category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://t.co" target="_blank" alt="none">Robena</a></td><td>Robena description</td><td>Robena category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://netscape.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Nikolaus</a></td><td>Nikolaus description</td><td>Nikolaus category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://walmart.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Cassie</a></td><td>Cassie description</td><td>Cassie category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Merrilee</a></td><td>Merrilee description</td><td>Merrilee category</td>
<tr><td><a href="http://vistaprint.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Kalinda</a></td><td>Kalinda description</td><td>Kalinda category</td>
<tr><td><a href="https://hubpages.com" target="_blank" alt="none">Carny</a></td><td>Carny description</td><td>Carny category</td>

    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: this worked perfectly - thanks a lot. Moved me fwd a notch in my learning, much appreciated.

Comment: @kroy2008 I'm so glad that I managed to help you ! If you find my answer useful, kindly, mark it as accepted.